# How can I set a default value for ion.rangeSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you help me to set the default value to my input?

As I submit the range that within the form it always take the min to max and it does not care about the default value that I put it in the input value.

How can I solve this problem?

```
    <input type="text" class="js-range-slider clicked"  id="rangeme" name="Project_Cost" value="-1" /> 
        <script>
            $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
                type: "double",
                min: 0,
                max:<?php  echo $max;?>,
                from: 0,
                values:$(this).find('.clicked').val(),
                to: <?php  echo $max;?>,
                grid: true
            });                      
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check this default demo

http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo.html

you need to put default variable using "from" parameter (in demo example from is 550 so on start 550 is selected), in your code from is 0 so slider is always on min which is also 0

Comment: So there is no way to get the value from input attribute value? As i set it -1

Comment: Hmm can you explain me what you are trying to do... in the range 0 to 100 value -1 is impossible...

Comment: yes i know is not impossible because that i want to set it as default to validate the form if the user add the range or not something like if (value==-1 ) alert ('no change '); else alert (the range value);

Comment: you can create some variable var updated = 0; than if user do something with slider using onUpdate to set updated to 1... I think that will cover your requirement